# Scheme Factorial (fact* l) Question

Tags: scheme

I'm a newbie at Scheme, so forgive the question: I have a function that calculates the factorials of a list of numbers, but it gives me a period before the last number in the results. Where am I going wrong?

## code:

```
#lang scheme

 (define fact
    (lambda (n)
      (cond
        ((= n 0) 1)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (else (* n (fact (- n 1)))))))

 (define fact*
   (lambda (l)
     (cond
       ((null? (cdr l)) (fact (car l)))
       (else
        (cons (fact (car l)) (fact* (cdr l)))))))
```

## output:

```
> (fact* '(3 6 7 2 4 5))
(6 720 5040 2 24 . 120)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have done is create an [*improper list*](http://www-pu.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/users/sperber/pfg-2001/scheme/schintro-v14/schintro_93.html). Try this:

```
(define fact*
   (lambda (l)
     (cond
       ((null? (cdr l)) (list (fact (car l))))
       (else
        (cons (fact (car l)) (fact* (cdr l)))))))
```

The addition of the `list` in the fourth line should make this work as you expect. Better might be the following:

```
(define fact*
   (lambda (l)
     (cond
       (null? l) '())
       (else
        (cons (fact (car l)) (fact* (cdr l)))))))
```

This allows your `fact*` function to work on the empty list, as well as reducing the number of places where you make a call to `fact`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do that with Scheme primitives? Is list a primitive?

Comment: I edited to add the second implementation after your comment above. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ah, superb! My "Little Schemer" knowledge was forgotten momentarily. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if you know (or even if it's relevant), but there's a scheme primitive called `map`. What it does is apply a given function to every member of a given list. So you could define `fact*` as `(define fact* (lambda (l) (map fact l)))`, and it would work the same way. Of course, you should know how to do it without using `map` first!

Comment: D'oh! Just noticed exactly what I said as a later answer!

Answer (score 5):

The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384399/scheme-factorial-fact-l-question/1384412#1384412) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384399/scheme-factorial-fact-l-question/1384414#1384414) have pointed out the reason why you get an improper list as a result of your `fact*` function. I would only like to point out that you could use the [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) `map`:

```
(define fact*
  (lambda (l)
    (map fact l))

(fact* '(3 6 7 2 4 5))
```

`map` takes a function and a list as arguments and applies the function to every element in the list, producing a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` instead of `cons`. `cons` is used to construct pairs, which is why you have the "." that is used to separate the elements of a pair. Here's an example:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (if (<= n 1)
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))

(define (factorial-list l)
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (append (list (factorial (car l))) 
              (factorial-list (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: Could you expand on that? Why exactly does the "." get inserted into my list when I cons an atom onto a list?

Comment: A "pair" is an object that contains two atoms. A "list" is a sequence of pairs with the property that the `cdr` of each pair is another list, with the exception that the end of the list is indicated by the "empty list" atom. So `(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c '())))` is a proper list, but `(cons 'a (cons 'b 'c))` is termed an "improper list" because the `cdr` of the second cons is not a list.

Comment: Because in your final step, you are constructing a pair that consists of a list and an atom, e.g., `(cons '(20 21) 120)` => `((20 21) . 120)`. To make it work properly, you need to convert 120 into a list.